# Javascript 'new Array' problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to use an array which is statically initialized as:

```
var my = new Array([30,10],[3,32])
```

I want to create this array dynamically but it seems it is not possible as it appends quotes and creates like this:

```
var my = new Array("[30,10],[3,32]")

function(data) {
var my = new Array(data);
}
```

I have tried `replace`, `substring` and any other possible way. Any body have any idea how to do this. This is very urgent.

Comment: So basically you're asking for `eval`?

Comment: you many want to see if you can just have it data come in as json and then treat it as such

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to create this array dynamically"*? Also, when you say *"... it seems it is not possible as it appends quotes..."* What do you mean by "it"? Certainly not the JavaScript interpreter, `var my = new Array([30,10], [3,32]);` is perfectly valid. It creates an array with two entries, each of which is, in turn, an array with two entries: http://jsbin.com/abemi4 It also works if the values come from other variables (e.g., rather than literals): http://jsbin.com/abemi4/2 In your quoted function, what would `data` contain?

Comment: Where does this string `"[30,10],[3,32]"` come from? If you create it, why do you create a string? You can add elements to an array with `arr.push()`.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[[30,10],[3,32]]");
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Because you can safely convert a String into an Aray this way I guess.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I wonder the same thing, I don't see the OP ever talking about JSON.

Comment: @pimvdb: But my impression was that he wasn't using a string. In fact, he seems to be complaining that something is mysteriously turning his arguments into a string, though I can't imagine what. Anyway, the question is pretty unclear, so your guess is as good as mine. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Oh I'm sorry, I thought 'dynamically' meant that (instead of hardcoding) a String at runtime is supplied, which has to be converted to an array.

Comment: @pimvdb: Could be! I wouldn't think that (there are *lots* of things you do "dynamically"), but hey... Unless @Deepak bothers to clarify, like I said, your guess is as good as mine. :-)

Comment: @pimvdb `JSON.parse` is not available everywhere, especially in _cough_ older versions of IE _cough_.

Comment: @Haochi: You're correct, but if I remember correctly there is a cross-browser JSON library somewhere.

Comment: @pimvdb, @haochi: *"if I remember correctly there is a cross-browser JSON library somewhere"* Several of them. Heck, there are three in Crockford's github repo alone: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/ But @pimvdb, when using something that is like not to work without additional support, probably best to call that out. I'd still like to know what the OP actually wants to do. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why not create something like this?

```
var my = [[30,10],[3,32]];
```

Comment: +1 This would be the preferred notation. But his original, as quoted, should also work (provided nothing's redefined `Array`), it doesn't take us into the parts of `new Array` that are...tricky...

Answer (score 1):

you should use JSON.parse or even eval

Comment: i know, but for this example it is suitable. you know what type of js you're evaluating